# Mirror an integer... in NDos' way

Tags: code-golf, integer, integer-partitions

## NDos' Numeral System

NDos' numeral system is a numeral system invented by me. It represents every nonnegative integer by a binary tree. Given a nonnegative integer \$n\$:

- If \$n=0\$, it is represented as the empty tree.
- Otherwise, the tree has a root. With the binary expansion of \$n\$:

  - The left sub-tree of the root recursively represents the **length** of least significant consecutive `0`s of \$n\$ (trailing `0`s).
  - The right sub-tree of the root recursively represents the more significant side of \$n\$ split right before its least significant `1`. In other words, the right side is the number with its trailing `0`s and their leading `1` stripped off.

For example, if \$n = 1100100_2\$, there are two trailing `0`s, so the left sub-tree will be \$2_{10} = 10_2\$. Without the trailing `0`s and their leading `1`, \$ n \$ becomes \$1100_2\$, so the right sub-tree has that value.

For illustrative purposes, here are the full representation of the trees for \$n=1_2\$ through \$n=1110_2\$:

[image: NDos' numeral system]

Note that the numbers of nodes is not monotone. The smallest counterexample is \$10010_2\$ and \$11000_2\$.

Here's a Haskell implementation of conversion between binary and NDos':

```
import Data.Bits

data NDosNat = Zero | Push1 !NDosNat !NDosNat deriving (Eq, Show)

intToNDos :: Int -> NDosNat
intToNDos x
  | x < 0 = error "intToNDos: Negative input"
  | x == 0 = Zero
  | otherwise = let
    lSZN = countTrailingZeros x
    in Push1 (intToNDos lSZN) (intToNDos (shiftR x (lSZN + 1)))

nDosToInt :: NDosNat -> Int
nDosToInt Zero = 0
nDosToInt (Push1 lSZN mBS) = shiftL (shiftL (nDosToInt mBS) 1 .|. 1) (nDosToInt lSZN)
```

(I couldn't convert from nor to `Integer` because of Haskell's poor bit manipulation API.)

## Objective

Given a nonnegative integer, treat it as represented in NDos' numeral system, and output its horizontal mirror image.

## Examples

Here are some mappings. All numbers are in binary:

```
0 ↔ 0
1 ↔ 1
10 ↔ 11
100 ↔ 111
101 ↔ 1000
110 ↔ 110
1001 ↔ 10000000
1010 ↔ 11000
1011 ↔ 100000000
1100 ↔ 1110
1101 ↔ 1000000
```

## Rule

**The input and the output must be integers natively supported by your language.**

Comment: I can use non-binary numbers?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena As long as they are native arbitrary-length integers, yes.

Comment: "output its horizontal mirror image" Can you elaborate?  How does one go from the tree pictures to this?

Comment: @Jonah By reflecting it by a vertical line. (So right sub-trees become left sub-trees, and vice versa)

Comment: The part I'm confused about is how do you go from a tree structure to a flat list?

Comment: @Jonah The description above establishes a bijection between binary and NDos'. It shouldn't be too hard to get its inverse. (Refer to the Haskell snippet)

Comment: Why isn't `1,0,0,0` like `1,0,0` but one longer? (Feels like I don't understand "The left sub-tree of the root recursively represents the length of least significant consecutive 0s of n (trailing 0s).").

Comment: @JonathanAllan `100` has two trailing `0`s, so it got the tree representing `10` as the left sub-tree. `1000` has three trailing `0`s, so it got the tree representing `11` as the left sub-tree.

Comment: Ah, the left tree is an "NDos integer-tree" _representing_ the number of trailing zeros after the last set bit, got it!

Comment: Why must I/O be arbitrary sized integers? This immediately rules out a large number of languages. Why not just go with our default rules?

Comment: @pxeger This rule is that troublesome? Link to the "default rules" about integers, please?

Comment: [Here are our default rules for I/O in general](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447); the [rule for integers specifically is just to assume that input will never cause an integer overflow](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8643). As long as the algorithm works in theory, it's fine. Note that [abusing limited number types to trivialise a challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245) is already disallowed.

Comment: Integers are commonly stored in JS as IEEE-754 numbers with 52 bits of mantissa. **But** bitwise operations are limited to 32 bits. **But** JS also supports BigInts with unlimited size. So how should _integers natively supported by your language_ be interpreted in that case? Is that 32 bits, 52 bits, or unbounded? (And that's why you should just rely on default I/O rules.)

Comment: @Arnauld I'd say "choose one for the purpose of code golf" in that case.

Comment: This sequence might be worthy of an OEIS entry - f(N) = NDos-mirror of N - 0, 1, 3, 2, 7, 8, 6, 4, 5, 128, 24, 256, 14, 64, 12... That's enough for a sequence.  (Though you'd probably need a better name for it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## x86 32-bit machine code, <del>29</del> 27 bytes

```
51 0F BC C8 74 13 D3 E8 D1 E8 E8 F1 FF FF FF 91 E8 EB FF FF FF 41 F9 D3 D0 59 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFfT8MgFMWfy6e41iyBrVv2J/FhrL747LuJMwultMUwukCrncu@uvWy6Zy@APcc7o8DyHEpZd/faitNmytY@SbX9aS6J38ko7P/mtO2DBrZbESDVdY2arOh1KlyJ9yWzhhjoG0DBQ2jYJwIvwVK4rWdlKbOhIFibYsl7FpfgZIdh8wXYZGAEli9foCyOQdfuSAkIM1VMeMghUEGh05W5VXfj4xhz1jfSA5Oml8KcvHcenf2nWp4TDAgCUm3QttzZFdK3F4JB8MhFm@MHEgUnA5SmCaw5yR6r7RRQDtYpTC7YySKdvgyTUHjgYY4wdt3oxFDdkQuzto@Cllpq0DWuVrGwT0hcc5rOPzsg8F0/oSMfUppa70urcpPeYasYM/IfWH8CN8J9nCDhO5hEWgXAsUU2b5Rnq0tkrpg4nVbZ8NpR9L3n7IwovT9eLuY44B/lGKvMl8)

Uses the `regparm(1)` calling convention – argument in EAX, result in EAX.

-2 by making the function preserve ECX, removing the need to save it for the recursive calls.

Assembly:

```
.global f
f:  push ecx        # Save ECX onto the stack.
    bsf ecx, eax    # ECX := position of lowest 1 bit in EAX (= left subtree number).
    jz e            # Jump to the end if EAX was 0, which will return 0.
    shr eax, cl     # Shift EAX right by the number from above, removing the trailing 0s.
    shr eax, 1      # Shift EAX right by 1 more, removing the first 1.
                    #  (Now EAX holds the right subtree number.)
    call f          # Recursive call; apply the function to the right subtree number.
    xchg ecx, eax   # Exchange the value in ECX (the left subtree number)
                    #  with the value in EAX (which is f(the right subtree number)).
    call f          # Recursive call; apply the function to the left subtree number.
    inc ecx         # Add 1 to f(the right subtree number).
    stc             # Set the carry flag to 1.
    rcl eax, cl     # Rotate EAX together with the carry flag left by CL,
                    #  which is 1+f(the right subtree number).
                    # This appends to EAX a 1 and f(the right subtree number) 0s.
e:  pop ecx         # Restore the value of ECX from the stack.
    ret             # Return.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 50 bytes

-5 bytes borrowing some tricks from [@Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241231/9288).

```
f(n,t=valuation(n,2))=if(n,(2*f(t)+1)*2^f(n>>t++))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLCsMwDIThqwxZWbECsfuALuKLhBa8STEEVwSl0NO78m7@j5F8lOktrW2usi7fvJ9Zy6daRaKldHZx3JySDzTGl0FK6j1RyyL7z1VMCXKUqjaHHgPsRMRYZ0ZgRMaVcWPcGQ@TrsbBPFye1P4)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,b=0:n and[f(n/2,b+1),f(b)*2+1<<f(n/2)][n%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BDoIwDIbve4pejJtO3HY0zBcxHiBIXAJlgR3g6bGdivHU9v//r21c0nNAt66t76q@bipAXXtzQaiwubUSz07XR6t0K2t1cEdblllU9xvu3H0NfRzGBNMyCdEOI3QBHxCQhWJKTcCLAECrAR14kAGTnMkYQ5RKg1PA0MwEk8UUu5Dkvjxd90oR2RPZM0lH6QkujvU40ibaC96zT7/mAzTY1QDhYITN1Qr7Fix335b7j28MRbeM4dDPMdk1P/s9/gcyv23O01/gBQ)

Takes in a non-negative integer and outputs the "mirrored" integer.

Use the recursive relation: If the left and right subtrees are `a` and `b` respectively, then the mirrored number will have `f(b)` and `f(a)` as left and right subtrees. To calculate `a` and `b`, I simply divide `n` by 2, then increment `b` by 1 until `n` is odd.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 58 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @att.

```
f@0=0
f@n_:=(2f@#+1)2^f[(n/2^#-1)/2]&[n~IntegerExponent~2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcm9CsIwFEDh3ae4ECgtpiS5/oBCJYuDm@AYUgmS1A69SskgiH31mIKL4/nO4OLdDy72N5dS0LKRi6Dpum9KDJotVYVtMCUJbFmtKoG2MDSdKPrOj8fX80Ge4oQ2nceeovmNS8zVGcYBLdQH@OdgmJ2PhQKEhrfkoHJzWHPYcNhy2GWZNbPKrlaf9AU)

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##Vcm9CsIwFEDh3ae4ECgtpiS5/oBCJYuDm@AYUgmS1A69SskgiH31mIKL4/nO4OLdDy72N5dS0LKRi6Dpum9KDJotVYVtMCUJbFmtKoG2MDSdKPrOj8fX80Ge4oQ2nceeovmNS8zVGcYBLdQH@OdgmJ2PhQKEhrfkoHJzWHPYcNhy2GWZNbPKrlaf9AU)

Comment: [Three 57 byters](https://tio.run/##bY09CsJAEEZ7TzEyEJSMZHf9ARUlrZ1iGdawkaymMEVYqxBrGw8h3swLeIQ4iSAIVsP3Zt43J@OO6cm4bG/q2oZiIeYmvthLEs/EYmUj9bw@DNnIBIoSX2rqSV/ZMOmrXQsHMlBad2xzi0tBPCQryAqygqjoK/mIw9bDj0VCe2y@bvey/HtB3barovKnjf9UlVdvzlnqwnWR5S5a5S49pMXWcTpESKA0DJbwi7lENxsNHgQhlIJAciYYEYwJJgRTJg1lLJnLYVW/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

A port of [Surculose Sputum's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241230/58563).

```javascript
f=(n,b=0)=>n&1?f(b)*2+1<<f(n/2):n&&f(n/2,b+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5BDoIwEIXhvafoinQE6QxLA3oIT0CREgyZEmi8fk1c6tPdLL788x79s9@HbV7TSeN9zDl0VivfMXUXLeQarKdjU0rbBquuobMWxfuqfCmUh6h7XMZ6iZMNlj0bY6hO8Za2WSfbEBnnDB8@nUAn346hQ5AhRFKQZAYrBUcZvRccZRhmYRjG9k8ajoZtgfR3Or8A)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

It is unclear what the *arbitrary-length integers natively supported by* JS exactly are. Here is a version assuming that's BigInts.

```javascript
f=(n,b=0n)=>x=n&1n?f(b)-~x<<f(n/2n):n&&f(n/2n,-~b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5LDoIwFIXhuavoiPQmPG4ZGoqLcAUUKcGQWwPEMGLrFeNMj8zO4Mufc2@ezdxOw2PJJNy6GL3VkjrLQrZerSRGLl47yra1qryWohQ6S5J8ZpptjmIbZA5jl4@h116zY1FKUb6E6zIN0uuSSBWF4tM3NBiaX/hOAojkTpFE1EDKDJ6aP1lGD4zgLMM0722YxvgoDo/juoH2IB5f)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 35 bytes

```
ＵＭＥ⊕Ｎ＆ι±ι⊞Ｏυ∧ι×⊕⊗§υ⊖Ｌ↨ι²Ｘ²§υ÷κ⊗ιＩ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY69DsIwDIR3nqKjIxUJWJkoXSrx04EXCI1FLZqkSpyWtw8JqlRxiy3f3Sd3vXSdlUOMVzmerdbSKEgrNKZzqNEwqrSPgW9BP9GBEGVREc/k8ZSiVBY3fElGIJGtNvj@PqKTbB2EslgyD9Lo/5i1Dc8hzRM3RuEnZ2tc7QuaF/dQSY@5fxA/Jb6d0xOHBF57jeGaJlII7wRZuCQWHTetI8Nwlp6htSOEfIxxv4vbafgC) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Calculates all of the mirror images from `0` to `n` inclusive and outputs the last one.

```
ＵＭＥ⊕Ｎ＆ι±ι⊞Ｏυ∧ι
```

For each integer `0` to `n`, calculate the maximal power of 2 that is a factor of it, or `0` for `0`. For each of those powers of 2, if the value is `0` then just push that, otherwise push...

```
×⊕⊗§υ⊖Ｌ↨ι²Ｘ²§υ÷κ⊗ιＩ⊟υ
```

... the result of looking up the number of trailing zeros, doubled and incremented and multiplied by 2 to the power the result of looking up the original value integer divided by the doubled power of 2.

```
Ｉ⊟υ
```

Output the last of the calculated values.